# Launch a debug session without running the program

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Currently in eclipse CDT, when I launch the application I have the option to choose in which function I want the debugger to stop (or not to stop at all).

I need to run gdb with an application without even starting it at all, the same as you would get if you would execute:

```
gdb program_exec
```

And then run it when I want it.

Also, is there an option to cancel the automatic "Yes" answering since I need some control through the console.

Also, if all the above is not possible, is it possible to connect to an existing gdb session ?(I could start a session as in the code section above, and then just connect to it)

Comment: Apologies if this doesn't make sense in the context of CDT, but can you not just set a breakpoint on main?

Comment: Choose "Debug configurations", then select your runner. You have a few control options over gdb. you can pause the debugger at main(), change the way it is launched, or push a bunch of commands to it. re linking to an existing process - doesn't seem like it's opssible, you'll need another frontend.

Comment: I need to stop before main()... I don't the program to start running at all. Just loaded to memory.

Comment: @BenjaminK. : How about a breakpoint on `_start`, the function which calls global ctors and then  `main`? That's before any of your code runs.

Comment: @MSalters. : Not good, I can't let the program start execute because I need it in memory and then attaching to another process. It is not just a symbols issue. This program knows that a debugger is connected. Basically it must be this way....

Comment: @BenjaminK. : a program *cannot* know anything if it doesn't run. It obviously has to execute at least one instruction to figure out whether a debugger is connected.